# SAS: Remove duplicated expressions from given list using REGEX

Tags: regex, string, sas, duplicates

I would like to remove duplicated expressions from a given string using SAS code. Each expression is delimited by a space and respects the following REGEX /[A-Z]_\d{2}.\d{2}(.[a-z])?/.

Here is the code:

```
data want;
text = "X_99.99.a X_99.99.a A_12.00 A_12.00 A_13.00 A_12.00 X_99.99.a";
do i=1 to countw(text);
Nondups=prxchange('s/\b(\w+)\s\1/$1/',-1,compbl(text));
end;
run;
```

The desired result should be:
Nondups ="X_99.99.a A_12.00 A_13.00"

What should be the regular expression to be used inside the function prxchange?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try `'s/([A-Z]_\d{2}\.\d{2}(?:\.[a-z])?)(?=.*\1)/$1/'`

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using REGEX?  Why not just use normal string functions?

Comment: The reason is my data set has several records like the one presented, but each line can vary in dimension and each substring inside can have different combinations of letters or numbers. I though REGEX would be better for this problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks. I tried but apparently is not working.

Comment: Yeah, you need no `$1` in the replacement. `'s/\s*([A-Z]_\d{2}\.\d{2}(?:\.[a-z])?)(?=.*\1)//'` should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Nondups=trim(prxchange('s/\s*([A-Z]_\d{2}\.\d{2}(?:\.[a-z])?)(?=.*\1)//',-1, text));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kILKUR/1)

The pattern matches:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([A-Z]_\d{2}\.\d{2}(?:\.[a-z])?)` - Group 1:

  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `_` - an underscore
  - `\d{2}` - two digits
  - `\.` - a dot (must be escaped)
  - `\d{2}` - two digits
  - `(?:\.[a-z])?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 sequences of a `.` and a lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=.*\1)` - a positive lookahead that requires any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the value stored in Group 1 immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Wiktor! Very useful.

Comment: just a follow-up question, probably linked to the positive lookahead. The regex expression doesn't  seem to match if text = "X_99.99.a X_99.99.b A_12.00 A_12.00 A_13.00 A_12.00 X_99.99.c". After the first iteration the substitute strings gets ".a X_99.99.b A_12.00 A_12.00 A_13.00 A_12.00 X_99.99.c".

Comment: @David It is related to token boundaries. Since they seem to be whitespace boundaries here, use `\s*(?<!\S)([A-Z]_\d{2}\.\d{2}(?:\.[a-z])?)(?!\S)(?=.*(?<!\S)\1(?!\S))`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kILKUR/2).